# How to discover trigger's parent schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

To discover all triggers in any given MS SQL Server database, I'm currently querying the sysobjects table (which is fine because it works in MS SQL Server 2000 which I have to support) e.g.

```
SELECT R1.name AS trigger_name, 
       T1.name AS trigger_parent_table_name
  FROM sysobjects AS R1 
       INNER join sysobjects AS T1 
          ON R1.parent_obj = T1.id 
 WHERE R1.xtype = 'tr';
```

This gives me a reduced list of trigger names and for each I can use

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'trigger_name_here'
```

to find the definition. That works fine for databases where only the default dbo schema is used.

I now have a MS SQL Server 2005 database which uses multiple schemas. What is the best way of discovering the schema for each trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the parent object for a trigger so it will always be a table. In sys.tables (system view) you get the schema_id and with it you can go sys.schemas (system view too) to get the schema's name.

Hope this helps.

--

EDIT:

The code:

```
SELECT     sys.objects.name AS [trigger], 
           sys.tables.name AS [table], 
           sys.objects.type, 
           sys.schemas.name AS [schema]
FROM       sys.schemas RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           sys.tables ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.tables.schema_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           sys.objects ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.objects.parent_object_id
WHERE      sys.objects.type = 'tr'
```

This is is with sys.tables but you can do it with only sys.objects, this is a general select to look for parents and schemas:

```
SELECT     O.name, O.type, S.name AS [schema], 
           OP.name AS parent_name, OP.type AS parent_type, SP.name AS parent_schema  
FROM       sys.schemas AS SP RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           sys.objects AS OP ON SP.schema_id = OP.schema_id RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           sys.objects AS O LEFT OUTER JOIN
           sys.schemas AS S ON O.schema_id = S.schema_id ON OP.object_id = O.parent_object_id
```